# Why are this div and textarea not the same height

Tags: html, css

See [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YUYJ3/3/).

html:

```
<div></div>
<textarea>something here...</textarea>
```

css:

```
textarea {
    height: 1em;
    float:left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;
    width: 20em;
}

div {
    height: 2em;
    float:left;
    width: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 1px;    
    border-color: #ff0000;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;    
}
```

Comment: textarea has height: 1em;
div has height : 2em;
difference is 1em?

Comment: @GertKommer the height is equal because of the `padding` on the textarea. But the textarea has a `font-size` of 13px while the div has 16px (at least in my environment).

Comment: @GertKommer, the textarea has padding which should make it the same height, top & bottom padding + height = actual height

Comment: my bad-_-' too quick response. you are right hsan and martincarlin87:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `em` unit is dependent on font size.

The default fonts for the body and textarea are usually not the same height (since they're not the same font)

I added `*{font-family:sans-serif}` and the height issue fixed itself.

Comment: but if there is no text in the div or textarea why should the text matter?

Comment: Just because there's no text doesn't mean font size isn't an issue. The `em` unit is defined according to the font size.

Comment: and because `textarea` has a different default fontsize as `div` the height is different?

Comment: Well yes, because like I keep saying, ***the `em` unit is DEFINED based on font size!***

Comment: I think I get it now. thx for the explaination:) hadn't used em before only px

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what your seeing.  What browser is this occuring in?
Ive made a few changes
http://jsfiddle.net/hgHLe/

```
    textarea {
    height: 1em;  
    float:left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;
    width: 20em;
}

.child {
    height: 2em;  
    overflow:none;
    float:left;
    width: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 1px;    
    border-color: #ff0000;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;    
}
.master{

    height: 2em;  

}



<div class='master'><div class='child'>:D</div>
    <textarea>something here...</textarea></div>
```

Added a .master
replaced your dive with .child

added overflow:none; to master aswell as 2em

additnly adding a forces font size

```
body{
font-size:12px;
```

}

Note!  dont forget Jfiddle has the normlizer CSS in use!

Answer (score 0):

Because they have different `font-size` and you are setting the height depending on the `font-size`.

Using Firebug I checked the `font-size` of both `div` and `textarea`, in the first case it is 16px and in the `textarea` 12px. This is a standard browser behaviour: they apply different font-size in `textarea` than the rest of the website. You can try applying the same font-size to both manually or using a CSS reset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a font-size on the parent container to unify measurements with em . 
I have made an edit to assign font-size to a container. Please review [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/YUYJ3/6/)

I have added a wrapper around it

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <textarea>something here...</textarea>
</div>
```